# What is meant by a potential of an object in context of electricity?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity

On my journey on learning about electricity and voltage in particular, I asked a few questions in this site. And I often come across terminology of relating potential to objects, like for example in [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/643908/if-i-touch-the-side-of-a-high-voltage-battery-will-i-get-shocked) I asked about whether or not will a person be shocked by touching only one pole of a high voltage battery, and I got:

> Because you are only touching one terminal of the battery, all of the charge that may flow into you will have the effect of bringing your potential closer to that of the battery terminal.

That confuses me, since it is explained that *potential* is a property of a *position*, not of an object. So what do people mean when they talk about *potential* of objects, like human beings?

Answer (score 1):

To a pretty good approximation, your skin is a conductor;  charge can flow over your skin pretty easily.  This means that any differences in electrical potential at different points on your body will get evened out as the charge flows across your skin, and you can talk meaningfully about the "electric potential of your body".  This also means that we can change the electric potential of any conductor by changing the amount of electric charge it carries.

This is illustrated quite forcefully if you shuffle your feet across a  carpet on a dry day, and then touch a metal doorknob with your hand.  The additional charge does not stay on your feet but migrates to the rest of your body, leading to a surprising jolt when you touch   the metal doorknob.

Comment: so saying "potential" actually means "electrically charged"? Are these terms used interchangeably?

Comment: @YoavKlein:  They're not interchangeable, but they're related to each other.  See my edited answer, particularly the sentence at the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert “To a pretty good approximation, your skin is a conductor”. 
According to: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/ “The skin contact resistance will usually be between 1000 and 100,000 Ω, depending on contact area, moisture, condition of the skin, and other factors. The skin thus provides most of the body's protection from electric current”.

Comment: @BobD:  My understanding is that while the resistance *through* the skin is relatively difficult, the resistance *along* the skin is much lower.  I'll admit that I'm not an expert in biophysics, though.

Comment: @BobD "Skin provides most of the body's protection from electric current" does not mean "skin is an electrical insulator". A good insulator would have a resistance of $10^{10}$ or $10^{12}$ ohms, not $10^3$ or $10^5$.  For comparison, "resistors" commonly used in electronic circuits which are meant to *conduct* electric current may be as high as $10^7$ ohms. Skin does provide some "protection" in the sense that it has a higher resistance than the material *inside* your body, though.

Comment: @alephzero I don't think I said skin is an insulator. I just pointed out it can have considerable resistance and because of that if current is flowing in the skin (either through it or along its surface) there is going to be a potential difference between two points on the skin, whereas  Michael stated " any differences in electrical potential at different points on your body will get evened out as the charge flows across your skin". When he said body, I assumed he meant different points of the skin. The internal body resistance if typically modeled by a 500 Ohm resistor.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I'm not an expert in biophysics either, but I would think the resistance through the thickness of skin (which is what the link is dealing with) would be less than the resistance along the surface of the skin. The former includes the epidermis (which has the most resistance) and the dermis, which is more conductive.  Whereas the surface is the epidermis.

Answer (score 0):

Potential depends on position (and nothing else) in *electrostatics* because the electric charges do not move. (That's why the subject is called electrostatics, as compared with electrodynamics)

If you touch one battery terminal, some charged particles (negatively charged electrons and/or positively charged ions) *move* between the battery and your body. After the electric charges have moved, the potential at every point in space has changed.

Comment: So now the potential of me and the potential of the pole are the same?