# Is there a small spark every time a switch is closed to engage a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, inductance, electrical-engineering, lightning

Suppose we have a simple circuit with a resistor $R$ connected to a DC voltage source $V_{\text{batt}}$. The circuit can be enabled or disabled by a switch. The dielectric breakdown of air is $E_{\text{breakdown}} = 3\times 10^6 \text{ V/m}$. This value will be exceeded when the switch contact is a distance

$$
d = V_{\text{batt}} / E_{\text{breakdown}}
$$

If $V_{\text{batt}}$ is small then $d$ will also be small, but there will always be some small distance where the breakdown will be exceeded and I would expect a spark.

If $V_{\text{batt}}$ is 10 V then $d = 3.3 \hspace{2 pt}\mu\text{m}$. This seems like you could notice a spark at this distance?

So is it correct that there is always a small spark when a switch closes? If not why?

I could imagine entering a regime with small $V$ where $d$ is so small such that $\tau = d/v$ where $v$ is the switch contact velocity is small enough that there isn't really time for the air to break down or the spark would be so short lived that it's not really measurable in any way.

This question inspired by [If I touch the “+” side of a high voltage battery, will I get shocked?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/643908/128186)

Note: I know that there is often a spark due to inductive loading when a switch is opened. This is NOT the effect I'm interested in. I'm interested in what happens when a switch is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enlarge slightly upon DKNguyen's answer:

Indeed, the thing that causes air to break down is the strength of the electric field in the gap between the switch terminals, as measured in volts per meter. For small values of the gap, even a small number of volts will produce a strong field.

Furthermore, if there are any sharp points or asperities on the contact surfaces, the field will be locally magnified at those sites, and dielectric breakdown will be initiated there.

However, also note that the kinetics of dielectric breakdown of gases have time delays associated with them, as they rely on statistics to provide triggers for ion production. It is common in experimentation with deliberate spark formation in gaps to not get a spark when your measurement tool is gated open simply because the gate time wasn't sufficient to accomodate the random perturbations required to trigger the discharge. For this reason, ultraviolet light will be beamed into the gap to promptly produce photoelectrons at the start of each test shot so you always capture a nice spark on every shot.
Absent that UV, it isn't assured that you'll get a spark every time you turn on the electricity.

If you want repeatable sparks, they can be encouraged by filling the gap with a specific gas chosen for its breakdown characteristics. In applications where sparking was desired (by, for example, in so-called *spark transmitters*), a variety of techniques including special gas atmospheres were used to stabilize and make uniform the sparks which were used to excite radio waves prior to the invention of vacuum tube circuits.

Switches can be deliberately designed to be "bounceless" by pushing the contact surfaces together with sliding motion instead of snapping them together under pressure, and by furnishing multiple slider contacts in parallel, in which the first slider to make clean contact short circuits the other sliders, and if that contact happens to bounce or rub against a chunk of dirt then the redundant sliders in the array pick up the current flow without interruption.

Comment: if the contacts were made to approach each other very slowly so that there is plenty of time for a spark then would you get a spark every time?

Comment: probably! but the other way to always get a spark in a gap is to smack the gap with some high-frequency content in the electricity being fed to it. Modeling the gap as a two-plate air-gap capacitor, we find the conductivity of the capacitor is much greater for high frequencies than for low, and the current across the gap excites the air in it into conduction lots quicker than if simple DC is applied across the gap. Don't ask me how I know, the resulting core dump will overflow your hard drive.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're asking about a mechanical switch and not a solid-state switch. Yes, there is a spark when you flip a mechanical switch closed because doesn't just close cleanly. It closes, then bounces open, then closed, then bounces open, etc. until it finally stays closed.

The voltage producing the arc is not the voltage from the supply. It is the voltage produced by the inductance when current flowing through it is suddenly interrupted and causes the magnetic field to collapse, releasing the energy stored in the magnetic field to try and maintain the current flow through the inductor prior to the interruption as best as it can. This voltage, is dependent on the inductance and the current running through it (i.e. the energy in the inductor) and can be very high even if the supply voltage is low.

Comment: Sorry I'm being jumpy with comments and edits. previously I asked if bounce was present in push switches.

Comment: @Jagerber48 They all have bounce unless maybe some kind of switch where one contact is permanently submerged in a conductive liquid like mercury and the other contact is dunked into it.

Comment: So I thought I followed your answer but now I'm not clear. I'm aware that a large voltage can build up across a switch when you try to OPEN it due to the inductively stored energy and that this can cause voltage much larger than the supply voltage that can lead to large arcs. But I'm asking about a simple dielectric breakdown due to the voltage supplied by the voltage supply that happens when CLOSING a switch at the point (or multiple points in time) when the switch contacts get close enough together.

Comment: @Jagerber48 Paraphrasing: Can just moving two contacts with a low voltage supply behind them arbitrarily close but without contact cause breakdown of the dielectric between them? For example, upon the *initial* approach of a switch contact closing against another switch. I think yes, because dielectric breakdown is measured in Volts per distance. But I'm an engineer so we don't really care about the technicality of something like that since it is so low power it would do no damage or wear so you'll have to ask a physicist.

Comment: yes, you're paraphrasing is spot on. So it sounds like you're saying, practically speaking, whether or not there's a spark in the situation I describe is never really limiting in practical electronics, but that bounce and inductive sparks are relevant. I could imagine the effect I describe being important when working with very high voltages, such as for power transmission.

Comment: @Jagerber48 Yes for power transmission the energies involved are a lot higher and the distances a lot larger. You can see the coronal discharge glowing even when it's just one contact. You don't want to get near that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge But you also seemed to specifically asked about low voltage.

Comment: Woah that corona discharge is scary :) yes you're right I asked about low voltage, I guess it wouldn't be surprising to see an arc when contacting a 40 kV terminal if you just slam it shut and don't do something smarter. I'm curious if the behavior persists down to low voltages and if not why. Definitely a "physics" minded question.

Comment: @Jagerber48 I believe I was told that in some power plants (old Soviet plants I think?) they detonate explosives to slam the contacts together because it needs to be done real quick or bad things happen.